# How to alter the datatype and Column width of existing column in teradata without recreating the table?

Tags: teradata

I have a table in teradata with column x as Small int .I need to change it to number datatype .how can I write the alter statement?

Comment: You can't. INT to NUMBER will change the internal storage which is not allowed. Create a new table and MERGE (more efficient than INS/SEL).

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply.is it the same for converting decimal to number?

Comment: Yes, different internal storage